# How to determine running environment type in cucumber runtime?

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, cucumber

I want to run a cucmber

I use `jenkins` to run `gradle` build and then run test with `cucumber` script.

I want to create a user for testing. If I run on DEV env I want to use `user1`. When running on QA server I want to use `user2`.

I can to use this zs_proile var:

export WEBDRIVER=local and user user2

but maybe reading from config file will be more generic

What would be the clean way to check in test during run time which env do I run in?

Comment: You can add profiles to Your build.gradle and set the values dependant on which env You prepare artifact for.

Comment: greate. can you add an answer with a link and I'll vote you?

Answer (score 0):

You can add profiles to `build.gradle` file and set values dependant on which env the artifact is prepared for. Some useful references: [using properties](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/11/gradle-goodness-using-properties-for.html) and [token filtering](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2010/11/gradle-goodness-add-filtering-to.html).

Comment: What do You mean exactly? I suppose that You need to do is to filter the properties file and then read it in java. It's not a good idea to filter (and replace) java sources that way and sources at all.

Comment: and if i don't need a whole config file. just one env var in java. how to do this?

Comment: No idea really. This is a well established practice to prepare deployable artifacts that way.